# Correct way of using ViewModel inside of pagebuilder elements?

Tags: magento2, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel that returns if a user is logged in or not and we need to add this functionality to `vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/widget/content/carousel.phtml` but we're unsure on the correct way to do this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, you cannot use view models out of the box. But I may be wrong.
But when the widget is rendered it calls the `toHtml` method from the block.
In your case, I think the block is `Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList`.

I think you can create a before plugin on the `toHtml` method from the block and attach your view model to the block..

something like this

```
namespace Venrod\Module\Plugin\CatalogWidget\Block;

class ProductsListPlugin
{
    private $viewModel;

    public function __construct(\Your\ViewModel\ClassHere $viewModel)
    {
        $this->viewModel = $viewModel;
    }
}


public function beforeToHtml(
    \Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList $subject
) {
    $subject->setData('myViewModel', $this->viewModel);
}
```

then you should be able to use in your template (which you should overwrite in your theme) this

<php $viewModel = $block->getData('myViewModel');?>

```
<?php if ($viewModel) : ?>
    your logic goes here
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Thankyou. I will try this method!